# SQL Server SSRS ReportServer Database Version Error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

This is probably a trendy question, But I promise you my problem is different.
Lately my server windows crashed and I was forced to install new windows.

I took a backup of the database "ReportServer" and "ReportServerTempDB".

Until then I didn't remember the SQL Server version was installed before the windows crashed.

Now when I try to attach these databases and run the report server, it tells me the following message

"**The version of the report server database is either in a format that is not valid, or it cannot be read. The found version is '163'. The expected version is '162'. (rsInvalidReportServerDatabase)**"

I've made some research, and understood that my current installed SQL Server version is higher than the database, I tried installing some cumulative updates but when I run the updates it seems not to be recognizing the SQL Server version installed.

Current installed version: **Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) 2014 v12.0.2000.8**

Previously installed version: **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Enterprise** Not sure though.

My problem is that I can't open the ReportServer database because it's version is older and I can't install the right cumulative update to fix this issue. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Much appreciated Thanksss!!.

Comment: Can be helpful https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104851/reporting-service-2014-service-pack-1-failing-to-work-with-error-wrong-databas

Comment: I think you have it the wrong way round. It is saying the report database is v163 but it should be 162. v163 was introduced in SSRS 2012 SP2 CU5 and SSRS2012 SP3. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32360.sspr-troubleshooting-the-version-of-the-report-server-database-is-either-in-a-format-that-is-not-valid-or-it-cannot-be-read.aspx

Comment: @DenisRubashkin thank you very much! this article helped me. Deleting the version number from the ReportServer database made it work.